# generate yaml file from envrionement variable in Windows

Tags: windows, yaml

I would export environement variable seted in Windows to yaml file

any tips to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell. This requires

```
Install-Module powershell-yaml
```

Then you can do

```
Import-Module powershell-yaml
$vars = @{}
Foreach ($v in Get-Item -Path Env:*) {
    $vars[$v.Key] = $v.Value
}
ConvertTo-Yaml $vars
```

We need to generate `$vars` because `Get-Item` returns an array of DictionaryEntries. I'm unsure whether there's a better way to get a hashtable of env vars.